# Android Studio Error:Execution failed for task ':app:instantRunMainApkResourcesDebug'

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Estou desenvolvendo um aplicativo `android`, quando tento dar run ou compilar meu aplicativo eu recebo a mensagem `Execution failed for task ':app:instantRunMainApkResourcesDebug'`.

O compilador aponta que existe um erro no android manifest na **linha 15**, porem não detecto discrepancia alguma sobre essa linha

> ```
> C:\Users\marco\AndroidStudioProjects\CoopTaxi\app\build\intermediates\instant_run_merged_manifests\debug\processDebugManifest\instant-run\AndroidManifest.xml:15: 
>    error: unexpected element <uses-permision> found in <manifest>.
> ```

Android Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="cooptaxi.projects.com.cooptaxi">
    <!--
         The ACCESS_COARSE/FINE_LOCATION permissions are not required to use
         Google Maps Android API v2, but you must specify either coarse or fine
         location permissions for the 'MyLocation' functionality.
    -->
    <uses-permision android:name="android.permission.ACESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".ClienteMapActivity"></activity>

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />

        <activity
            android:name=".MotoristaMapActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_motorista_map" />
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".MotoristaLoginActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".MapaActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".ClienteLoginActivity" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Build Abaixo:

```
Executing tasks: [:app:assembleDebug]


> Configure project :app
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)

> Task :app:buildInfoDebugLoader
> Task :app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:compileDebugAidl NO-SOURCE
> Task :app:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:checkDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:prepareLintJar UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:generateDebugSources
> Task :app:javaPreCompileDebug UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:mainApkListPersistenceDebug UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:writeDebugApplicationId UP-TO-DATE

> Task :app:processDebugGoogleServices
Parsing json file: C:\Users\marco\AndroidStudioProjects\CoopTaxi\app\google-services.json

> Task :app:mergeDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:createDebugCompatibleScreenManifests UP-TO-DATE

> Task :app:processDebugManifest
C:\Users\marco\AndroidStudioProjects\CoopTaxi\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml:24:9-31:50 Warning:
    activity#com.google.firebase.auth.internal.FederatedSignInActivity@android:launchMode was tagged at AndroidManifest.xml:24 to replace other declarations but no other declaration present

> Task :app:processDebugResources
> Task :app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:instantRunMainApkResourcesDebug FAILED
> Task :app:buildInfoGeneratorDebug

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:instantRunMainApkResourcesDebug'.
> Android resource linking failed
  C:\Users\marco\AndroidStudioProjects\CoopTaxi\app\build\intermediates\instant_run_merged_manifests\debug\processDebugManifest\instant-run\AndroidManifest.xml:15: error: unexpected element <uses-permision> found in <manifest>.


* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 13s
18 actionable tasks: 6 executed, 12 up-to-date
```

Answer (score 0):

Esta linha parece estar errada

```
<uses-permision android:name="android.permission.ACESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

você colocou `uses-permision` ao inves de [`uses-permission`](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-permission-element?hl=pt-br), tenta colocar desta forma

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```